# Powershell get the full HostName from Get-DnsServerResourceRecord

Tags: powershell, dns

i'm trying to make a csv with all Hostnames and their RecordData from multiple DNS Zones. When using Get-DnsServerResourceRecord however i only get 1-3 octets of the Hostname depending on which Reverse Zone im going through, the output looks like this:

HostName, RecordData
12      , [www.test.com](http://www.test.com).

i want the whole HostName though not only the last octet in that case "12". I tried to come up with a solution which takes the Zone name, removed the arpa suffix and turns the octets around however i cannot get it to work, is there an easier method?

Tried to DNS Resolve against the RecordData FQDN's, which doesnt work in alot of cases,
Tried to write a custom function which alters the ZoneName to fit which didnt work because i couldnt get the octets to Turn around.

Comment: The preceding octets are part of the zone namespace - you already know :)

Comment: What is the actual `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` command you're running? For instance how exactly are you calling it, with what options/parameters etc as that makes a difference.